# Python - How can I line up the equals sign of all my equations?

Tags: python, alignment

Currently in maths class we are working on gcd and I have written a Python script on my NumWorks calculator.

Here is the code I already wrote :

```
def div(n):
  return [x for x in range(1,n+1) if n%x==0]

def pgcd(x,y):
  a = x
  b = y
  
  while b > 0:
    reste = a % b
    print(a, "=", a//b, "*", b, "+", a%b)
    a,b = b,reste
      
  return "PGCD("+str(x)+";"+str(y)+") = " + str(a)
```

And it ouputs this :

```
pgcd(178,52)
178 = 3 * 52 + 22
52 = 2 * 22 + 8
22 = 2 * 8 + 6
8 = 1 * 6 + 2
6 = 3 * 2 + 0
```

I want it to output that :

```
178 = 3 * 52 + 22
 52 = 2 * 22 + 8
 22 = 2 * 8 + 6
  8 = 1 * 6 + 2
  6 = 3 * 2 + 0
```

I've read many articles online but I have no idea how to put that into my code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`rjust`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=ljust#str.center) string method.

The thing is you need to figure out what is the widest string on the left hand side you will print. Luckily here, it would be the first value.

So I would go with this.

```py
def pgcd(x,y):
  a = x
  b = y

  len_a = len(f"{a}")

  while b > 0:
    reste = a % b
    print(f"{a}".rjust(len_a), "=", a//b, "*", b, "+", a%b)
    a,b = b,reste

  return "PGCD("+str(x)+";"+str(y)+") = " + str(a)
```

Should print this.

```
>>> pgcd(178,52)
178 = 3 * 52 + 22
 52 = 2 * 22 + 8
 22 = 2 * 8 + 6
  8 = 1 * 6 + 2
  6 = 3 * 2 + 0
'PGCD(178;52) = 2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.format()` to achieve this:

```py
'{0: >{width}}'.format(178, 3)
'{0: >{width}}'.format(52, 3)
```

Will output

```
178
 52
```

Answer (score 0):

See `.format` for strings. An example of right justifying would look something like `print('{:>6}'.format(42))`

You can also use [`rjust`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust)

Answer (score -1):

Ok I asked it on a Discord server and they found out so if anyone is having the same problem as me here is the solution (did not put all code for space) :

```
def pgcd(x,y):
  a = x
  b = y
  
  maxi = len(str(a))
  while b > 0:
    reste = a % b
    print(" "*(maxi-len(str(a))),a, "=", a//b, "*", b, "+", a%b)
```

Basically compare to original code we added a maxi variable that has the maximum lenght of my integers, and then if the int is smaller like 8 compare to 178 we add to spaces because the difference of their length is 2.
This explanation is probably not 100% correct but it helps getting an idea.